# Material UI access children of container

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am using material UI for my project and I am sick of naming tone of `className` for each item of my component so I have a question like this:

```
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { Button } from "@material-ui/core";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  container: {
    background: "pink"
  },
  item: {
    height: "200px",
    width: "200px",
    background: "lightblue",
    margin: "10px",
    "&:last-of-type": {
      background: "red"
    },
    h1: {
      color: "green"
    }
  }
}));

export default function container() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.container}>
      <div className={classes.item}>
        <Button variant="contained" color="primary">
          Primary
        </Button>
      </div>
      <div className={classes.item}>
        <h1>Text in 2nd item</h1>
        <input type="text" />
      </div>
      <div className={classes.item}>
        <h1>Text in last item</h1>
        <Button variant="contained" color="primary">
          Primary
        </Button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image]

As you can see in the code up here I have a container with a pink background contains 3 lightly blue background items:

The first item has a button import from '@material-ui/core', the second one contain a `h1` text and an input and the last one has a `h1` text and a button import from '@material-ui/core'.

I want to change color of `h1` text in the second item by modifying `className` `item` ( please do not name any `className` in that `h1` tag ) into yellow

and I want to change background color of Material Ui button in the last `item` only (the style of Material UI button from the first item is still remained) by overriding `className` `.MuiButton-containedPrimary` in `className` `item` as well

Feel free to change the code in this codesandbox link [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-access-style-fn1ic). Thanks for your help, it means a lot to me, sincerely have a good day

Answer (score 0):

nested CSS selectors can be used in this case.

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  container: {
    background: "pink"
  },
  item: {
    height: "200px",
    width: "200px",
    background: "lightblue",
    margin: "10px",
    "&>h1":{
      color:'green'
    },
    "&>button:last-of-type": {
      background: "red"
    },
  }
}));
```

[Here](https://cssinjs.org/jss-plugin-nested/?v=v10.5.1) is the JSS documentation.

Here is the working demo:
[image: Edit stackoverflow access style (forked)]